# Ionic4 Angular AuthGuard works for home page and not for sign in page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, angular-router-guards, auth-guard

I have created an Authguard for my web app and have assigned into several routes like Home, Sign-in, Sign-up etc.

Expected Behavior:

1. Home page  - the intention is to show the login page if the user is not logged in
2. Signin , Signup, Forgot Password etc - the intention is to redirect the user to the home page if he has already logged in (to avoid displaying the Sign-in page to a logged in user, if the user types the url in the address bar)

Actual Behavior:

1. If a user who has not logged in visits the home page, he is being redirected to Sign in page, but the page is not displayed.
2. If a user visits the Sign-in page by URL, again the page is not displayed. [ No matter if the user is logged in or not]
3. If I remove the auth guard for the Sign-in page, Loading the home page redirects the user to Sign in page and the page is displayed properly.

My AuthGuard code

```
 @Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
    private storageService: LocalStorageService
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => !!user),
      tap(loggedIn => {
        const url = route.url.toString();
        if (url === ROUTE_SIGNIN || url === ROUTE_SIGNUP || url.includes(ROUTE_FORGOT_PASSWORD) ) {
          if (loggedIn) {
            this.router.navigate([ROUTE_HOME]);
            return of(false);
          }
        } else if (url === ROUTE_HOME) {
          const skipped = this.storageService.getValue(KEY_SIGNIN_SKIPPED);
          if (!loggedIn && !skipped) {
            this.router.navigate([ROUTE_SIGNIN]);
            return of(false);
          }
        }
        return of(true);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Routes:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: ROUTE_HOME,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: ROUTE_HOME, loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: ROUTE_NAV_LIST, loadChildren: './pages/list/list.module#ListPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
  { path: ROUTE_SIGNIN, loadChildren: './pages/signin/signin.module#SigninPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: ROUTE_SIGNUP, loadChildren: './pages/signup/signup.module#SignupPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
  { path: ROUTE_FORGOT_PASSWORD, loadChildren: './pages/forgot-password/forgot-password.module#ForgotPasswordPageModule'
    , canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
  { path: ROUTE_PHONE_VERIFICATION, loadChildren: './pages/phone-verification/phone-verification.module#PhoneVerificationPageModule'
    , canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },

];
```

I can understand that the problem here is with assigning the Authguard to the login page. But I couldn't identify what is causing the problem. Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Comment: instead of returning `return of(false)` or `return of(true)` just return `true` or `false`

Comment: tried that already. didn't work either

Comment: Show your routes as well. In your place, to reduce complexity, I would make 2 guards, `AuthenticatedGuard` - any route attached will require user to be authenticated and `UnauthenticatedGuard` - any route attached will require user to be un-authenticated. This way it easier to manage, no need to do this complex `if`s etc.

Comment: @muradm I have edited the question and added the routes. I also tried adding a separate UnAuthGuard which would just check the loggedin status and redirect it to home if it was true. But it did not make any difference. I'm not sure what I'm missing in that simple piece of code.

Comment: did you try to put your authentication inside the `app.component.ts` file and inside the platform ready function?